# Windows Authentication header token not being sent?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-authentication

I'm trying to get a ASP.NET application to use windows authentication. I have disabled anonymous auth and enabled windows auth in IIS7. On my dev box (my workstation, localhost) I can use fiddler and see proper token is passed in through the header and I'm not prompted. Everything is working fine and I'm authenticated as my domain user.

However, on a remote server on our domain, with identical settings, I continually get prompted. We need it to automatically send the domain authentication for windows auth.

Does anything in IE need to be configured for this to happen for a remote machine on the same domain? Could someone explain why this may not be working and what needs to be checked? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your IE zone settings, I don't think IE is set to automatically send DOMAIN\Username credentials in an non Intranet zone. You can set this with a group policy at some point but for now set it manually in your IE settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. However, the dev box is still on the same domain. Do I still need to add the site to the list? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the remote server is on the same domain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would thinks so because the "dev" box probably, in most cases, would use RFC1918 address space. (10.0.0.x etc) which is not routeable on the Internet.

what is the name of the dev box?
Is it a RFC1918 IP?

If the Dev box is on the domain then AD DNS is most likely putting it in the Intranet zone.
In this case add it to the list of sites.

Comment: Both my dev box and the remove server are on the same domain. The IP is RFC1918 (10.0.X.X). Still add to the list? We're working with our network engineering group to do so. Thanks.